# Proof of $\left| x\right| <1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, x^n=0$.

Tags: calculus

Struggling with the proof:

If $\left| x\right| <1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, x^n=0$.

The proof is given like this:

[image]

Now this is how I see it, but Im not sure where I am going wrong so I would like to get a correction of where my ideas become faulty.

I see the first $\log ^n(\left| x\right| )$ as the "lower" function and $e^{n \log (\left| x\right| )}$ as the "upper" function then I would expect after taking the limit of the function that they both would convert to a say L, and since I am able to define the original function to be in-between these two functions which both have limit L, so does the original function.

However the 'lower' function has limit of negative infinity and the 'upper' have limit at zero. No this do not provide a squeeze.

Could someone please explain what Im missing. I tried visualising it but since the lower function given the initial i function is decreasing linearly and moving toward negative infinity I am not able to see what is going on?

Comment: The $\log(|x|^n)$ is not the lower function. $|x|^n$ is the upper function and $-|x|^n$ is the lower function and it is calculated by writing it as $e^{\log(|x|^n)}$.

Comment: Remember that $\log^n |x|$ and $\log (|x|^n)$ aren't the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-|x|^n$ is the "lower" and $|x|^n$ is the "upper":
$-|x|^n \le x^n \le |x|^n$

And both have zero as limit because:

[image]

---

PS. There is no $\log^n(|x|)$ in the proof, but $\ln(|x|^n)$. It's not the "lower" function (nor the "upper"), but it's used as a lemma for finding the limit of $|x|^n$.